# My nav bar is under the slideshow. i want it over but i can't figure out

Tags: html, css, slideshow, nav

My nav bar is under the slideshow. I want it over but i can't figure out. I tried some absolute and relative positions but it doesn' work. Please find my a solution and if you have time give me a logical explaning.

My html page

```
 <!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css">
    <title>
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle2.min.js"</script>
    <!Daca e IE><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htm5.js"></script><!End>   


</head>

<body>


    <nav>
        <a href="#">Logo</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Projects</a> 
        <a href="#">Colections</a>
        <a href="#">Philosophy</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">Facebook</a>
    </nav>




<div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <img src="images/233H.jpg" alt="blabla">
    <img src="images/233H1.jpg" alt="blabla">
    <img src="images/233H2.jpg" alt="blabla">
</div>    





</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

My css page

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;

    }       
.cycle-slideshow {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 2000px;

    }


nav {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;

    }
nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgb(239,239,239);
    margin: 15px 32px 0 32px;


    }
nav a:hover {
    color: pink;
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle???

Comment: Your code is working fine

Comment: what do you mean by my code is working fine?

Answer (score 1):

use `z-index` property for this

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index:10;
}
```

use maximum if slider also used

> z-index

Answer (score 0):

The nav position is being ignored because it is set to *fixed*. To solve this add padding to the slideshow that equals the height of the nav.

```
.cycle-slideshow{
    padding-top: 45px;
}
```